# OnClick Button give only first row value in ajax jquery php mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When i click on Button(id=button) its give me only first row value from Hidden (input "id=close")..

I have list of array but on when i click on close button all its give first row id ..why so

Below is my code file:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('input[id=button]').on('click delegate keypress ', function(e){
                     e.preventDefault();
                     var id= $('input[name=close]').val();
                     var mainid = id;
                     alert(mainid);
                             $.ajax({
                                type:\"get\",
                                url:\"test.php\",
                                data:{
                                id:mainid
                                },
                                success:function(data){
                                  if(data){
                                      alert('Close Sucessful');
                                      }else {
                                       alert('Something Went Wrong');
                                      }
                                }
                            }); 
                });
           });
   </script>";
```

---

```
function processdasa($row){
     $a =" <input type=\"hidden\" name='close' value=\"".$row['id']."\" id=\"close\">
           <input type=\"button\" value=\"".$row['id']."\" id=\"button\">
         ";
     return $a;
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","ght");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($con, "abc");
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    mysqli_query($con , "UPDATE testtable SET  closed=1  WHERE id=$id ");
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**For more clarification here is my LIST :**

```
$result = get_list();
if($result){
$cols = array(
         _("id") => array('align'=>'center'),
         _("Name") => array('align'=>'center'),
         _("Closed") => array('align'=>'center','function'=>'processdasa')
); }
```

***Hence it will look like :***

```
Id |  Name |   Closed
------------- ----------------
1  |  ABC  |    1 (BUTTON)
2  |  RF   |    2 (BUTTON)
3  |  GF   |    3 (BUTTON)
4  |  GF   |    4 (BUTTON)
```

Comment: `$row['id']` contain single id or array of id????

Comment: u have to use `class` instead of `id` otherwise try `$('input[id^="button"]')`

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia  $row['id'] conatin array of id ..

Comment: 'input[id^="button"]'  i tried this .. but same .. when i click on row 3 button , i get alert of row 2 value and when i click on row 2 button i get prefect alert value "2"

Comment: any one here what ..please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$row['id']` is array of id then you have to make these change
change name close in this function to carry array of id as `close[]`

```
function processdasa($row){
     $a =" <input type=\"hidden\" name='close[]' value=\"".$row['id']."\" id=\"close\">
           <input type=\"button\" value=\"".$row['id']."\" id=\"button\">
         ";
     return $a;
}
```

now in your test.php

```
<?php
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","ght");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($con, "abc");
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    //$id is an arry so first implode it
    $new_id=implode(",",$id);
    //and now in your query us IN keyword
    mysqli_query($con , "UPDATE testtable SET  closed=1  WHERE id IN($new_id) ");
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for reply , but when i use name='close[]' i am getting alert " undefined "

Comment: @ Dk-Macadamia , check now i have edit my question , its how my list comes